# How does Android maintain concurrency for the R file?

Tags: android

I am working on a project that emulates the R.java and Resource/AssetManager of android. I have created a parser that scours a `res` folder for valid xml resources and creates a static class holding all the ids to reference the resources. That was the easy part. Now I'm stuck trying to figure out how android maintains the concurrency between the ID and the resource element. As far as I can tell, android doesn't create another file to connect R to a resource.

Is the id in the R file and link to a resource implicit? Meaning that the id is generated and assigned a value based on the order in which is was found in the resource folder, and that this "binding" only works because resources were compiled in that exact order. Or is there something behind the scenes that connects an application and its R class to resources?

Comment: Don't hold me to it, but I believe it's implicit. If you change id's in your XML, for instance, it screws up the resources until you clean the project. Some id's can get mapped to other resources, etc.

Comment: @Geobits That's the impression I'm getting, too, just from chasing down the "Resource cannot be found" exceptions cause by invalidated R files. Thanks for you input.